# How to trigger script after changes in graph editor?

Tags: python, animation, customization, add-on, shortcut

I'm improving upon the motion path in Blender. As it is now, the motion path is something that needs to be calculated for each bone, then updated manually. I want to make the motion path (for the active bone) update every time I change something in the graph editor.

I have this simple script:

```
import bpy

bpy.ops.pose.paths_update()
```

That I want to trigger, every time I make a change in the graph editor. Is this possible? Is there a simpler way of doing it, rather than trigger a script?

What I currently have, is the above script as an operator. I then reference this operator with a hotkey. But I want to remove the need for a hotkey.

Comment: Are there any of the predefined Application Handlers that can detect a change in the graph editor? For instance bpy.app.handlers.scene_update_post?

Comment: There is no app handler for what you want, but you could check if there's a way to dirty-check for changes (`.is_updated`, `.is_updated_data`?). It will probably be a performance killer however.

Comment: This sounds like it may be the current limitations of Blenders dependency graph. If so, Sergey Sharybin has been redesigning it as part of the Gooseberry branch.  https://builder.blender.org/download/